# Control the screen reader - Make screen reader to read when a particular element has rendered

Tags: javascript, accessibility, nvda

I'm working on a simple application and I want it to make it accessible through screen readers.

**Problem Area**:

- Screen Readers on web pages Actual Behaviour: I see that the screen
  reader waits for the page to load completely (excluding the
  dynamically generated elements) and then it starts reading from top
  to bottom

**What I expect**: I want the screen reader to start reading based on a condition say after a div gets injected dynamically.

I have tried a multiple ways to make the content accessible using aria-live, aria-busy, focus() methods.

My code is as below:

```
<div><h1>NVDA TEST</h1></div>
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000" title="iframe" style="height: 500px; width: 100%;"></iframe>
<footer>
    <span>Hello Company</span>
    <span style="float: right">Terms and conditions Apply</span>
</footer>
```

I want the above behavior to be implemented in a bigger application.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do here. Where are you trying to have the screen reader start, and why do you want to create a behavior that's different from the default? You stated that the "condition" that you want to use to influence the screen reader behavior would be something like a div being dynamically injected. This sounds like the behavior that aria-live would be perfect for, but you've stated that you already tried that. Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute you are supposed to use if you want to control what ends up in (or rather, what is *excluded* from) the accessibility tree is `aria-hidden`.

Have you tried wrapping the content you want to hide with `aria-hidden="true"`, and then remove the attribute at the moment you want to reveal the content?

At some point there's going to be an html attribute called `inert` which will be best practice for this kind of thing at some point. It's not fully standardised yet, but you can use it with a [polyfill](https://wicg.github.io/inert/explainer.html). (Please inspect the first of the use cases mentioned in the linked document - I think it is very close to what you need).

Comment: I have used combinations of aria, focus to achieve the above behavior but there wasn't any expected behavior. Thank you so much for suggesting me to use the inert attribute using which now I'm able to achieve the required behavior. The problem now is the screen reader( the screen reader should read after removing the inert attribute) doesn't read the content. Is focus is the only way to make the screen reader to read the content??

Comment: no, focus is not the only way. Screen reader will be able to handle browsable content as long as it uses standard semantics, particularly headings, but also lists, paragraphs and so on. NVDA uses "H" to focus the next heading, for exampe.
If you put `tabindex=-1` on a heading for content which gets inserted dynamically, you can focus it with javascript at an appropriate moment.